# I miss the network icon when update my ubuntu from 9 to 10

Tags: ubuntu

When I finish updating with my system, then the network in the top right is gone, who can help me to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file: `/etc/NetworkManager/nm-system-settings.conf`

Change:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

To:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

And then reboot the system.

Also check if `nm-applet` is running. In my case `nm-applet --sm-disable` is running.